# App crashing after RequestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, delphi

I know there are already some questions regarding RequestLocationUpdates crashes, but I didn't find an answer yet for my specific problem.

With `LocationManagerService` I start a request for location updates with `minTime = 1000` and `minDistance = 1` for measuring a golf ball hit/distance. Usually, this works just fine. But from time to time the app crashes (no error at all, app just terminates and restarts). What I guess is that the system terminates my app because of it is taking too much performance. I am really not sure, but that's the only thing I can imagine.

So, if I am right, what could I change to avoid this issue? If I am probably not right, what else could cause the issue?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards

Andy

Important parts of source code (Delphi) below:

```
procedure TFormStartMeasure.ButtonMeasureTap(Sender: TObject;
  const Point: TPointF);
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
begin
  try
    if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then begin
      LocationManagerService := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
      if not Assigned(locationListener) then
        locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
    end;
    FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locationListener, TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
    FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  except
    try
      if Assigned(locationListener) then
        FLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
      TimerRelease.Enabled := true;
    except
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormStartMeasure.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
var
  locAccuracy, locLatitude, locLongitude: Double;
begin
  if MeasurementAborted = true then
    exit;

  try
    locAccuracy := location.getAccuracy;
    locLatitude := location.getLatitude;
    locLongitude := location.getLongitude;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Even if it doesn't post an error, a logcat could help. Things like improper rotation handling or other things not related to LocationManager may be the problem.

Comment: Can you put up the code to help you

Comment: I added most important parts of source code. Since it crashes after some time only, it must be something with the loop/listener.